# Option reference as member of struct

Tags: rust

How to get rid of the below lifetime error where in I'm setting one of the Option reference member variable to refer to local function stack variable.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::mpsc;

struct Mt<'a> {
    list: HashMap<u32, Data>,
    to_be_processed_data_ref: Option<&'a Data>,
    hash_map_data_ref: Option<&'a Data>,
    rx: mpsc::Receiver<Data>,
}

impl <'a> Mt<'a> {
    fn new(rx: mpsc::Receiver<Data>) -> Self {
        Mt {
            list: HashMap::new(),
            to_be_processed_data_ref: None,
            hash_map_data_ref: None,
            rx,
        }
    }
    
    fn add_to_hash_map(&mut self, k: u32, data: Data) {
        self.list.insert(k, data);
    }
    
    fn check(&mut self) {
        let data = self.rx.recv().unwrap();
        
        // make use of self.hash_map_data_ref and self.to_be_processed_data_ref in other Mt member functions and set them to None at the end
        self.to_be_processed_data_ref = Some(&data);
        for (_, val) in &self.list {
            self.hash_map_data_ref = Some(val);
            self.test1();
            self.test2();
            self.test3();
        }
        
        self.hash_map_data_ref = None;
        self.to_be_processed_data_ref = None;
    }
    
    fn test1(&self) {
        // access self.hash_map_data_ref and self.to_be_processed_data_ref
    }
    
    fn test2(&self) {
        // access self.hash_map_data_ref and self.to_be_processed_data_ref
    }
    
    fn test3(&self) {
        // access self.hash_map_data_ref and self.to_be_processed_data_ref
    }
}

struct Data {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

impl Data {
    fn new(x: f32, y: f32) -> Self {
        Data {
            x,
            y,
        }
    }    
}

fn main() {
    // Create a simple streaming channel
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Data>();
    let mut mt = Mt::new(rx);
    
    mt.add_to_hash_map(1, Data::new(10.0f32, 20.0f32));
    mt.add_to_hash_map(2, Data::new(100.0f32, 200.0f32));
    mt.add_to_hash_map(3, Data::new(1000.0f32, 2000.0f32));
    mt.add_to_hash_map(4, Data::new(10000.0f32, 20000.0f32));
    mt.add_to_hash_map(5, Data::new(100000.0f32, 200000.0f32));
    
    tx.send(Data::new(1.0f32, 2.0f32));
    mt.check();
}
```

Comment: @cafce25 I don't think that duplicate is right. The struct doesn't seem self referential because data isn't being moved into list before being referenced.

Comment: @nanofarad `for (_, val) in &self.list {
            self.hash_map_data_ref = Some(val);` stores the `val` which is a reference to part of `self` inside of `self`, which is self referential.

Comment: Ah, right, I missed this while focused on the data ref and the issues coming from it. IMO both the dupe and the answer I gave regarding data should be useful to OP

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's a fundamental issue with the lifetimes here, and your best bet is to refactor `test1`, `test2`, and `test3` to simply take `data` and `hash_map_data_ref` by reference.

Superficially, the pattern of:

```
let data = self.rx.recv().unwrap();
// make use of self.hash_map_data_ref and self.to_be_processed_data_ref in other Mt member functions and set them to None at the end
self.to_be_processed_data_ref = Some(&data);
// call self.testX functions
self.to_be_processed_data_ref = None;
```

would *seem* to be valid - you drop the reference before `data` is dropped or moved. However, there are two issues here:

- First, the borrow checker doesn't recognize patterns of this nature, and works too statically to recognize it. An `Option<&'a Data>` field in an `Mt<'a>` requires that whatever reference you place in the field must reference an object that lives as long as `'a`, and even if you promise to clear the reference quickly enough, that doesn't satisfy the static checks on how long `self` and `'a` live vs how long `data` lives.
- Second, this code is actually unsound if any of the `test` functions panic and the panic is caught. Normally, a caught panic can lead to *broken invariants*, but such a pattern should not lead to unsoundness.

  However, in this case, a panic will allow callers to observe a dangling reference: `data` is dropped as the panic is unwound, but the reference remains. [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ef24d21d412d43bd6229cb938f28e7d1) is an interactive demo showing the program break as a dangling reference is encountered. For answer completeness, I'll include a copy of the code at the bottom.

The exact structure would depend on what you need to do with the list and map reference, and I wasn't able to figure that out exactly. However, here's a skeleton that should work:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    rx: std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<String>,
    list: std::collections::HashMap<u32, String>,
}
impl Foo {
    fn add_to_hash_map(&mut self, k: u32, data: String) {
        self.list.insert(k, data);
    }
    fn check(&mut self) {
        // pass the value in instead of calling recv
        // This shouldn't change the behavior much
        let data = self.rx.recv().unwrap();
        for val in self.list.values() {
            self.test1(&data, &val);
            self.test2(&data, &val);
        }
        
    }
    fn test1(&self, data: &String, map_val: &String) {
        if data == map_val {
            println!("foo")
        }
    }
    fn test2(&self, data: &String, map_val: &String) {
        if data.len() == map_val.len() {
            println!("bar")
        }
    }
}

fn main() {

    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel::<String>();
    let mut foo = Foo {
        rx, list: std::collections::HashMap::new()
    };
    foo.add_to_hash_map(1, "hello".to_string());
    foo.add_to_hash_map(2, "apple".to_string());
    tx.send("apple".to_string());
    foo.check();
}
```

Note that you won't be able to mutate `self.list` in `test1` or `test2` because the iteration over the list already borrows from it. I would suppose that given the signature of `test1(&self)`, this shouldn't be an issue for you.

---

Unsoundness demonstration:

```
use std::panic::AssertUnwindSafe;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    x: Option<&'a String>
}
impl <'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn set_and_test(&mut self) {
        let s = "hello world".to_string();
        unsafe {
          // Pretend the borrow checker let us do what we wanted to do
          // using the minimum amount of unsafe possible
          self.x = Some(&*(&s as *const String));
        }
        self.action();
        self.x = None;
    }
    fn action(&self) {
        panic!();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo {
        x: None
    };
    // Caller calls a panicking function and catches the panic
    let _ = std::panic::catch_unwind(AssertUnwindSafe(|| {
        foo.set_and_test();
    }));
    // Normally this should be sound (but may expose broken invariants)
    // However, in this case, foo.x will be a Some(dangling reference)!
    println!("{:?}", foo)
}
```